# retrieve part of string and replace whole with another

Tags: shell

I have a file, where I need to look for first 3 characters of string and replace whole srting.

my file contains like this:

/mangeg/list1/list2

I need to replace mangeg to mandev, here "man" in constant, so I need syntax to search for man*** replace with mandev.

Thanks.

Comment: what are list1 and list2? the string 'mangeg' seems like dir not a file. but you said 'file'

Comment: You seem to be wanting to use `/` as a delimiter, but you need to make that explicit.  Do you want to replace all characters between `man` and the next `/`?  Or do you want to replace exactly 3 characters?  Or do you want to replace everything up to the first character preceding the next `l`?  Computers can't read your mind.   Be explicit, write down exactly what you are trying to match, and the appropriate regex will be clear.

Answer (score 0):

It's really not clear what you mean by "string", but perhaps you mean alpha-numeric.  Or perhaps you just mean any character that is not `/`.  Try one of:

```
sed -e 's@man[a-zA-Z]*@mandev@g'
```

or

```
sed -e 's@man[^/]*@mandev@g'
```

Comment: @meg I don't understand your comment.  Perhaps you are asking how to pass your data to `sed`: `sed -e 's@man[a-zA-Z]*@mandev@g' input-file` will do that, or put the `sed` command in a pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

whoami|cut -c5,6,7----=gives dev

sed -e 's@man[a-zA-Z]*@man`whoami|cut -c5,6,7`@g' file_name

with this I am geting manwhoami|cut -c5,6,7 instead of mandev

any inputs plz.

Comment: This is not clear and not an answer. It should be a comment.